# Как скопировать из одного объекта в другой только нужные свойства?

Tags: typescript

У меня есть два интерфейса:

```
interface IPerson {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}
```

и

```
interface IEmployee {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   salary: number;
}
```

и нужно скопировать данные из объекта типа `IEmployee` в объект типа `IPerson`. Но если это сделать так:

```
const person: IPerson = { ...employee };
```

то в объекте `person` окажется и свойство `salary`, что меня не устраивает.

С `Object.assign` ровно такая же ситуация.

Как мне скопировать только те свойства, которые есть в типе объекта-приёмника?

UPDATE: Забыл упомянуть, что решения, основанные на конкретных именах свойств, типа

```
const { name, age } = employee;
const person = { name, age };
```

не устраивают, т.к. в реальном приложении в этих интерфейсах много свойств, плюс в процессе разработки их состав часто меняется. Поэтому нужно *универсальное* решение.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно просто заранее создать "пустой" экземпляр класса и вместо деструктуризации пройтись по его полям и если в объекте `employee` есть эти поля, то забрать их. Если 100% всегда в `employee` будут все поля интерфейса `IPerson`, то провекру в цикле можно опустить

Код:

```
interface IPerson {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}

interface IEmployee extends IPerson {
   salary: number;
}

const PersonTemplate: IPerson = {
  name: '',
  age: 0
}

const employee: IEmployee = {name: 'Name', age: 18, salary: 1000};
const person: IPerson = {} as IPerson;

const copyField = < T extends {} > (k: keyof T, target: T, source: T) => {
    target[k] = source[k];
}

for (const key in PersonTemplate) {
    const keyName = key as keyof IPerson;

    if (keyName in employee) copyField(keyName, person, employee);
}

console.log(person);
```

Comment: Решение завязано на имена свойств (они в `PersonTemplate`), поэтому не является универсальным.

Comment: @OlegIshchenko В JS нет такого, чтобы бегать по именам полей какого-то интерфейса. Даже когда вы создаёте класс наследующий какой-то интерфейс вам нужно бывает в первый раз, все поля прописывать. Вы же всё равно прописываете все поля для интерфейса потому скопипастить просто все поля внутрь экземпляра - не является проблемой

Comment: Проблема дублирования кода не в том, что трудно скопипастить один раз, проблема в том, что при каждом изменении нужно не забыть исправить код в двух (или N) местах. Человеки, конечно же, забывают -- и здравствуйте, баги.

Comment: Вы пишите на TS-е потому при добавлении нового поля в интерфейсе, он непремнно сообщит о том что, где-то кто-то при имплеменетации интерфейса не указал все поля. В самом же нативном JS нет понятия интрейфейс, потому вам надо где-то создать список необходимых ключей, которые вы хотите взять у другого объекта

Comment: Согласен, хороший довод в пользу Вашего решения.
Но именно в силу описанного Вами поведения приведённый Вами код не компилируется: в строке `const person: IPerson = {};` ошибка "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IPerson': name, age".

Comment: Эту проблему можно решить так: `const person: IPerson = {...PersonTemplate};`.

Но всё равно не компилируется вот это: `person[key] = employee[key]`, потому что `key` имеет тип `string`, а должeн быть union type `"name" | "age"`.

Comment: @OlegIshchenko Обновил код, теперь всё рабочее :)

Comment: Доработал Вашу идею для максимальной универсальности. Т.к. не могу разместить в комментарии (объём не позволяет), оформил как отдельный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
const employee: IEployee = ???;
const {salary, ...person} = employee;
```

переменная `person` внезапно удовлетворяет интерфейсу `IPerson`

Comment: Решение абсолютно не универсальное, и, внезапно, принципиально ничем не отличается от того примера, что я привёл (см. в UPDATE).

В случае изменения состава свойств в `IEmployee` нужно будет ВРУЧНУЮ найти ВСЕ подобные присваивания и их подправить, что, конечно, не приемлемо.<br>  

Я даже не говорю о том, что здесь приведён синтетический пример, а в реальном приложении `IEmployee` может отличаться от `IPerson` десятком свойств или даже больше.

Answer (score 0):

Доработанная до максимальной универсальности идея от @Mr. Man: одна универсальная функция + по одной функции на каждый тип, в который нужно преобразовывать:

```js
// universal function

function createFrom<T extends {}>(source: T, template: T) {
  const target = {} as T;
  for (const key in template) {
    const keyName = key as keyof T;
    target[keyName] = source[keyName];
  }
  return target;
}

// types

interface IPerson {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}

function createPersonFrom(source: IPerson) {
  const template: IPerson = {
    name: '',
    age: 0
  }
  return createFrom(source, template);
}

interface IEmployee {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   salary: number;
}


// work

const employee: IEmployee = { name: 'Name', age: 18, salary: 1000 };

const person = createPersonFrom(employee);
console.log(person);
```